# RStudio is executing every call I make twice

Tags: r, rstudio

Every time I execute a line in RStudio, either by using control-enter in the script code or by making a call in the console (even as simple as `x = 2`), the call is made twice - simple example:

```
> x = 2
> x = 2
> x
[1] 2
> x
[1] 2
```

Where I only called `x = 2` and then `x`.

This isn't really causing any problems for me yet, but it's just kind of annoying. Any ideas?

Comment: This happened to me last week when I had a `.Rproj` open.  Closing the project and restarting R worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

This also happened to me. Every time I opened RStudio, I had to close the current project and reopen it to stop running the code twice.

It [seems](https://www.google.com.br/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=R+studio+runs+the+command+twice) that many users have experienced the same issue, and one [answer](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/communities/public/questions/200963296-Commands-repeating-in-console) that came up raised the possibility of being a bug related to previous versions of RStudio.

Comment: I've had something similar.  Oddly, when I press one in the script window to run a line, it runs but in the console window another line -- unrelated but one I have called sometime relatively recenty before --is inserted.  This just started a week or so ago.  I deal with it by going to the console and pressing ESC.  It is such an irregular event that I can't reproduce it.

Comment: @user2583119, yes very strange indeed. Have you tried to update your R studio's version?

Comment: Andre Silva: in fact, now that you make me think of it, I upgraded and perhaps the odd behavior began after that!  It's one of those things I just don't pay attention to until it happens a few times.  thanks for the tip, though